# useState is not getting updated first time

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I want to get the value of `res data` but when I click the login page for the first time I shows empty object and at the second attempt I am getting the value , can someone please help.

Here is my code:-

```
  const [Bol, setBol] = useState({})
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const { email, password } = Input;
    if (!email || !password) {
      alert("credential can not be empty");
    }
    await axios
      .post("/register/login", {
        email: String(email),
        password: String(password),
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.statusText = "OK") {
          history("/grains");
          setBol(res.data);
        }
      }).catch((error) => alert(error.response.data.error))
      
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchData()
    console.log(Bol)
  };
```

I want to get the value of `setBol`.

In first attempt when I submit i get :-
`{}`
empty object after that on second attempt i am gettting the value

```
{_id: '62c909af424cef53e15dfcc6', email: 'a@a.com', accessToken: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2M…5MDN9.FxbPnbANp1OXcLPJMJxR4rTC2yItCLunxjEDXWYNiRE'}
```

can someone please help how can i access data in first attempt

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be history.push and try to do setState before history

Comment: fetchData is asynchronous. The log happens before the setBol is called.

Comment: If you want to log the value of Bol as it changes, try this `useEffect(() => console.log(Bol), [Bol]);`

Comment: the value is there in the `Bol` with your first click , on set state the component re renders and as your console is inside `handlesubmit` it wont fire and show the bol values , try placing `console.log(Bol)` outside the `handleSubmit` then you will be able to see logged value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get an empty object when you first click on Submit is because fetchData() is an asynchronous function, it will execute this function when you click on Submit but this doesn't mean you get your response back from the api immediately. At this point, it will return a pending Promise, and will execute console.log(Bol) immediately right after. This explains why you get {} because this is the default value that you set (useState({}}). Now it has printed the default value of "Bol" to the screen, and you received the response from the api, and it will now call setBol() function. Your component re-render, but this is too late. If you click on Submit again, it will now print the value of "Bol" that it updated from the previous handleSubmit() call. I hope this is clear.

Comment: So what should I do , can you please tell

Comment: It really depends on what you want to do with Bol after the first attempt. If you want to use it as a prop and pass it down to a child component, you can simply do so without any issue, or if you want to render the value directly on the current component. If you could provide more information on how you intend to use it, I could be further of help.